# Is product of two DH's OK?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I have my own version of DH. It is basically a product of two DH's. It does provide authentication preventing MITM attacks without signatures but no forward secrecy if the private keys, as well as key exchange transcript between them, are fully compromised. Like this:

Alice has a private Key $s_a$ in Group $G_a$ of order $q_a$ modulo $p_a$ with generator $g_a$ as $P_a=g_a^{s_a}, (G_a,p_a,q_a,g_a,s_a,P_a)$.

In EC cryptosystem it is scalar multiplication. Similarly Bob has $(G_b,p_b,q_b,g_b,s_b,P_b)$.  During communication
Alice generates $x_b$ in $[1..q_b]$ and sends $h_b=[x_b]g_b$  to Bob
Similarly, Bob generates $x_a$ in $[1..q_a]$ and sends $h_a=[x_a]g_a$ to Alice.

Then the shared secret is $[g_a^{(x_a s_a)}]\cdot [g_b ^ {(x_b  s_b)}]$
They each calculate one part using own private key and the received message and the other one using the other side's public key and the generated secret $x (a/b)$. If forward secrecy is ignored, is there any problem with this?

I am surprised, DH is not used in PGP as much. Why?

Comment: I've modified a bit into $LaTeX$ / MathJax . Could you check all?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, as you are multiplying elements that come from different groups.

Comment: @fkraim, it can be in the in the group modulo (pa*pb) in DL groups.  It is trickier in EC, but we should still be able to define a larger group and add those two points. Otherwise the shared secret can just be Hash of two secrets concatenated together. P.S. I was just trying find a way to provide authentication without signatures

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks, hb=gb ** xb. Not [xb]gb, it's the only issue

Comment: @ManishAdhikari It is ECC then it is scalar multiplication, not exponentiation.

Comment: I did say gb**xb means scalar multiplication in case of ECC. Thanks for clarifying tho. My description was in general case. By the way, we do need to define point addition of points from different groups for ECC as well.